# menu active in static html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with single header and footer, and I include header and footer in home and about pages, how the active class working

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="">menu1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="">menu1</a></li>
    <li><a class="" href="">menu1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is using javascript and CSS the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's  will not run properly in there so i give you my git repo for clone : [enter link description here](https://github.com/abdullahalnoor/menu-active-in-static-html-page). (dummy example).

**Note:**

1. you need to run in host : http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html.. or other .. i run it vs code (live server)
2. I do it by matching window.location.pathname and a href url ..
3. maybe  there is many way to match  current path a tag url
4. if you have issue please comment. also i need to solve this problem for my own purpose

```js
  // after page loaded  and page refresh  this will run to active current <a> tag
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            activeClass();
        });
       // after <a> button click
        document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(function (btn) {
            btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
             
                activeClass();
            })
        })


        function activeClass() {
            document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(function (btn) {

                // get href index.html or about.html or contact.html and add slash (/)
                var href = '/' + btn.getAttribute('href');

                // get path /index.html or /about.html or /contact.html from current url
                var pathname = window.location.pathname;

                // check click <a> element that contains .btn class
                if (btn.classList.contains('btn')) {

                    // check a href (/index.html) and current pathname (/index.html) are equal then add active class
                    if (href == pathname) {
                        btn.classList.add('active')
                        console.log('1')
                    }


                }

            });
        }
```

```html
<a href="index.html" class="btn ">Home</a>
<a href="contact.html" class="btn ">Contact</a>
<a href="about.html" class="btn ">About</a>
```

Comment: how to add active class in <li> tag

Comment: @andrewghosh please learn about javascript dom traversal .... it's easy ...

Comment: @andrewghosh you need to do  something like  btn.parentElement .classList.add('active')..  it's depend on our html structure( node tree) ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = window.location.href;
var page = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if (page) {
  $('#menu_holder li [href="' + page + '"]').addClass('active');
} else if (page) {
  $('#menu_holder li [href=!"' + page + '"]').addClass('active');
} else {
  $('#menu_holder li:first').addClass('active')
}
```

```css
.link_active {
  background: #fff;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu_holder">
  <li class=""><a href="?varx=home">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="?varx=about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its working but,i try only use JavaScript ,in javascript how to use?

Comment: that's `javascript` I wrote, I don't know what you're expecting.