# Trying to change the background color and text color for the current link

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the background color and text color when a link in a nav bar is pressed.

i used the .currentLink style but it is still not applying to the current link. I'm sure i am missing something simple but cant seem to find any help in my coding books or online tutorials.

This is what i have so far in the css style sheet but it is not working still:

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul.vertical {
    flex-direction: column;
}

nav ul.horizontal > li {
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #1177d1;
}

nav ul.horizontal > li > a {
    flex-direction: row;
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.currentLink {
   color: #aa0000;
   background-color: #007700;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="home_page.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="test_page.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="photo_page.html">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact_page.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: the currentLink class does not seem to be used in the markup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have an onclick effect in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use this code**

```
nav ul.horizontal > li:active{
     
   background-color: #007700;
}
nav ul.horizontal > li > a:active {
   color: #aa0000;
}
```

```css
   nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul.vertical {
    flex-direction: column;
}

nav ul.horizontal > li {
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #1177d1;
}

nav ul.horizontal > li > a {
    flex-direction: row;
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


nav ul.horizontal > li:active{
     
   background-color: #007700;
}
nav ul.horizontal > li > a:active {
   color: #aa0000;
}
```

```html
   <nav>
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="home_page.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="test_page.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="photo_page.html">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact_page.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: if you want keep color and format.. you need to use  js... you can fllow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423341/menu-active-in-static-html-page/63424587#63424587).. i made it  by js - menu active in static html page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a framework like bootstrap or similar, it may be that the styles are being stepped on, in this case you can use **!important** in your css to step on the styles of the framework:

```
nav ul.horizontal > li > a:active {
    color: #aa0000 !important;
}
```